# Is it ok to invoke startService on Application rather than Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-service

Basically, the title, also note that this will be for a foreground service. Are there any implications from that choice? Thank you.

E.g. when you do

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

and similarly when you do

```
context.bindService(new Intent(context, MyService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and

```
context.unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

If the `context` variable above is the Application rather than an Activity.
This is for a foreground service. Are there any ill-effects or reasons not to invoke these methods on an Application?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "invoke startService on Application".

Comment: thx for taking the time to reply, i've updated the question with a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `Context` is fine for those operations. You are welcome to use an `Application` for those if you feel that it is appropriate. In fact, for `bindService()` and `unbindService()`, using `Application` over `Activity` is highly recommended, to be able to keep your binding across a configuration change.

The only limitation that I can think of is that I'm pretty sure you need to call `unbindService()` on the same `Context` on which you called `bindService()`.

Comment: thanks a lot! agreed, I assumed the bind/unbind MUST be on the same context also, for correctness.